# Yii2 : let a form-filed‘s value depends on another,how to write ajax

Tags: php, ajax, yii2

As it's showed bellow, one may input the `amount` and `fee-rate` field, but the `fee` is setted automatically (`fee=rate*amount`),so people won't count it by themselves.

```
<div class="loanr" id="loan-rate"><?= $form->field($model, 'amount')?></div>
<div class="loanr" id="loan-rate"><?= $form->field($model, 'fee-rate')?></div>
```

How to change this line:

```
<div class="loanr" id="loan-fee"><?= $form->field($model, 'fee')?></div>
```

I can use `ajax`, but I don't know how to imply this in `Yii` form filled.

Comment: why not using javascript evets to calculate and show fee value in disabled input? There is no need to use yii

Answer (score 1):

In view put this code:

```
<?php
$this->registerJs("$('#rate, #amount').keyup(function(){
        var rate = $('#rate').val(),
            amount = $('#amount').val(),
            fee = 0;
        rate = rate - 0;//convert to integer
        amount = amount - 0;//convert to integer
        fee = rate * amount;
        $('#fee').val(fee);
});"); 
?>
```

And form:

```
<div class="loanr" id="loan-rate"><?= $form->field($model, 'amount')->textInput(['id' => 'amount'])?></div>
<div class="loanr" id="loan-rate"><?= $form->field($model, 'fee-rate')->textInput(['id' => 'rate'])?></div>
<div class="loanr" id="loan-fee"><?= $form->field($model, 'fee')->textInput(['id' => 'fee'])?></div>
```